# Share list between multiple forked processes (C)

Tags: security, multiprocessing, fork, pipe, share

I have a list of integers in a main process.
The main process chooses an integer from that list, and forks out a child process to do something with it.
When the child process is finished I need it to notify the parent that it's done, so that integer can be reused.
There can be multiple child processes at the same time (each one gets a unique number from the list).

Thoughts:

1. using a regular file that holds the numbers, where the parent can remove a number from the file, and a child can insert it back (sorting is unnecessary) [is that a secure/safe way?].
2. using a pipe [do I need a separate pipe for every single child?]
3. shared memory?

Please advise me on the preferable method.

Comment: Any reason you're not using threads instead of processes here?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with multithread coding yet. other than that, no reason at all. how would it be beneficial in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) here, one per child, since a pipe is... well it's a pipe, and data may only flow in one predetermined direction (you would need two pipes per child to get a bidirectional communication).

A pipe is really simple to use and manage than shared memory, and the concept is more straightforward.

Do not use a file on disk for that. Piping is the way to go.

Use [`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to wait for any new data from any of the main process' children. You will need to request the `POLLIN` event for each pipe (read side) file descriptor in the main process. When a child closes its pipe (write side) file descriptor, your `poll()` call will unblock with a `POLLHUP` returned event for that child. This is your "child X is finished" signal, so you may remove its entry from the poll list and its integer is free to use again.

If you need to get some result back from the child (I'm not sure), `poll()` should unblock with a `POLLIN` returned event for any child writing data to its pipe. Then the main process may [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) from the pipe.

Children may [`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) the resulting integer as is to the pipe:

```
int some_result;

/* ... */

write(pipefd[1], &some_result, sizeof(some_result));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I failed to understand why it's not possible to use the same output fd returned by pipe for all the forked children (no need for bi-directional communication, only the child notifies the parent).

Comment: Then you would need another way to identify each single child in order to know which one finished, reading some ID from this single pipe.

Comment: Oh, the specific child is not important in this case, only the integer that it used, which, incidentally, can be used to identify the child, since it's unique.